# Keep selected tables synchronized across MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, replication, amazon-rds, data-synchronization

I've a need that requires me to keep a number of tables from a database (db1) synchronized with another database (db2). db1 & db2 have **different structures** and a set of tables and their data from db1 will need to kept up to date in db2.

I couldn't find a straight forward way to do this via MySQL replication and I'm open to any suggestions. One crude way is to export the tables from db1 at night, drop them from db2 and import them there. I worry about this approach and would prefer something that doesn't require me to drop any tables. I could also run a script that collects all the data that has been added/modified/deleted in the due course of the day and then runs a script on db2.

Both the databases are hosted on Amazon RDS, on two different instances.

Any suggestions?

Comment: use SQLyog ultimate tool.  for http://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-data-sqlyog-job-agent/

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/dms/ is also worth a look